# How to obtain dynamic google map url (have static map url)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Anyone please help me to obtain a dynamic map url for the following static map url.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=59.4,43.4&map_type=SATELLITE&markers=color:blue|label:b|59.4,43.4&sensor=false&size=400x300&zoom=10

Comment: Did you want it embedded in your web page, or just the map hosted on maps.google.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a list of Google Map parameters at http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters — too many to copy out and list in an answer here.

Your map would be http://maps.google.com/maps?q=59.4,43.4&t=k&z=10

Note: It's not possible to specify a particular marker in Google Maps, so there's no parameter for a blue marker. And your `map_type=SATELLITE` in your URL should be `maptype=satellite`: no underscore and lower-case. The `t=k` in the Maps URL specifies satellite view.

If you want to embed it in your site, the `<iframe>` code needed is

`<iframe width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=59.4,43.4&amp;t=k&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;z=10&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=59.4,43.4&amp;t=k&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;z=10&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>`